# create react app production build breaks material-ui v1.0.0 components in npm module

Tags: webpack, babeljs, material-ui, create-react-app

I am creating an external react component with nwb and material-ui v1.0.0-beta.5, link it with my main package that was scaffolded with create-react-app with `npm link`.  If I run `npm start` it renders properly and everything works well, but if I run `npm run build`, most material-ui components are terribly rendered.
I get this
[image]
instead of this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be a class conflict. Implementing JssProvider fixed it for me:

```
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
      dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS: false,
      productionPrefix: 'c',
});
```

Then your app tag with the following

```
<JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
```

See the following: [Github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11843)

Comment: Thanks for this! i thought it was fixed because after we updated it stopped, but if it ever comes back this will sure help.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the beta version of Material UI.
Recently, they released a stable version.
Try removing all the dependencies to the beta versions.